# How to combine two array into a list which have a inner-list?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I had two list:

```
a=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
b=[2,5,12,2,3,8,9,4,6]
```

And I wanted to get:

```
c=[[0,2,5,12],[1,2,3,8,9],[2,4,6]]
```

A and b correlated to each other, `a[i]` related to `b[i]`, when the value in `a` change like `0` to `1`, `12` end in the first inner-list of `c`.

I tried it with if else statement but it failed

How to get c in python?

Comment: Show us how you'd do this with list iteration.

Answer (score 1):

This code produces `c` in a good enough way (provided `a` and `b` are always adjusted in the same way as in the example):

```
a=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
b=[2,5,12,2,3,8,9,4,6]

c = []

i = 0

while i < len(a):
  d = a.count(a[i])
  c.append([a[i]] + b[i:i + d])
  i += d

print(c) # ==> [[0, 2, 5, 12], [1, 2, 3, 8, 9], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `zip` the lists, group by first value from `a`, and make lists with the second:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

a=[0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
b=[2,5,12,2,3,8,9,4,6]

[list(map(itemgetter(1), group)) for _, group in groupby(zip(a, b), key=itemgetter(0))]

#[[2, 5, 12], [2, 3, 8, 9], [4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Thierry Lathuille's answer, but does actually prepend the keys to the sub lists as requested by OP:

```
import itertools as it

ib = iter(b)
[[k, *(next(ib) for _ in gr)] for k, gr in it.groupby(a)]
# [[0, 2, 5, 12], [1, 2, 3, 8, 9], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my simple solution. Notice that you are splitting the list by by the counts of elemets in the list a. deque is used for popping elements in O(1) time from the left.

```
import itertools 
from collections import Counter, deque

a = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2]
b = deque([2,5,12,2,3,8,9,4,6])
c = Counter(a)

new_list=[] 
for x in c:
    new_list.append([x]+[b.popleft() for i in range(a[x])])
```